# Detect Complex Dice Formats

Tags: javascript, regex

I am currently working on a program that scans a page and highlights dice rolls and then lets you click to rolls those dice.

The program mostly works as expected, for example if the page contains stuff like `1d6`, `1d6 + 3`, `d20`, or `1d6 x 100`  it picks up and rolls it. However I would like the ability to detect more complicated roles for example `1d20 + 4 1d12 + 12` and then parse that out into its individual roles. I would like to avoid detecting things like `1d20 + 4 the 1d12 + 12`, basically, avoid things that have words instead of spaces in the dice roll.

My script uses regex to match patterns on the page and highlight them. I am not sure if this is something I could add to my regex since this is really been my project for learning regex. Here is the current regex I am using

`([+−-]\d+)|(([1-9]\d*)?d([1-9]\d*)\s*([+-−]\s*\d+)?([,]\s*\d+)?)`

And a sample on https://regexr.com/3tl1o

Comment: Could you provide some docs about this syntax? How can I know what's should be matched or not? Is this it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice_notation?

Comment: Also, in your regexr, what's matched that shouldn't be (or vice versa)?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

`((?:[+-]?[1-9]\d*)?d[1-9]\d*(?:\s+[-+x]\s+[1-9]\d*)?(?:\s+(?:[+-]?[1-9]\d*)?d[1-9]\d*(?:\s+[+-x]\s+[1-9]\d*))*)`

See https://regex101.com/r/Ap0HZw/1 for the explination